# Underscores Instead of Whitespace in Vim

Tags: vim, whitespace, underscore.js

I'm not sure what I did, but somehow I have underscores where whitespace should be when I edit a file in vim. Can someone tell me how to get my whitespace back?

This is my version info.

> VIM - Vi IMproved 7.0 (2006 May 7, compiled Jan  8 2013 23:52:09)
>
> Included patches: 1, 3-4, 7-9, 11, 13-17, 19-26, 29-31, 34-44, 47, 50-56, 58-64, 66-73, 75, 77-92, 94-107, 109, 202, 234-237

Thanks!

Comment: Is it visually underscores or actual underscores?

Comment: Vim 7.0 is from 2006 and _very_ outdated. It should be possible to install the latest version 7.3; if you can't find a proper package for your distribution (for Windows, check the binaries from the [Cream project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cream/files/Vim/), it's also not very difficult to [compile](http://www.vim.org/download.php) (e.g. from the Mercurial sources) on Linux.

Comment: They are actual underscores. I can backspace them out. They appear anywhere the space key was used. :set nolist doesn't help.

Comment: @EricL You could also backspace visual underscores out it would seem to do the same thing. Can you open the file in a different text editor and see if the underscores are still there. (If they are not a screen shot in vim maybe be useful). It might also be useful to see if they still show up when running without a vimrc (`vim -u NONE`) or without plugins (`vim --noplugin`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the substitute command:

```
:%s/_/ /g
```

Additional information in `:help :s`.

Comment: I did this, quickly discovered that it removed all of my underscores, intentionally written ones and not, q!, and when next I vim'd the file, all of the unexpected underscores were gone. I don't understand why this worked, but it did.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar symptoms. The underscores were actually showing the result of inadvertently searching for spaces by typing / . Got them to disappear by typing /AnyOtherString